# NSInvalidArgumentException', reas-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[4]'

Tags: ios, objective-c, null

i got error NSInvalidArgumentException this is my model class

```
+(NSArray *)users
{
    NSDictionary *user1 = @{@"username" : @"master photographer", @"email" : @"worldtravel@me.com", @"password" : @"drowssap", @"age" : @24, @"profilePicture" : [UIImage imageNamed:@"person1.jpeg"]};
    NSDictionary *user2 = @{@"username" : @"Lots of tots", @"email" : @"otterskips@me.com", @"password" : @"icecreamrocks", @"age" : @65, @"profilePicture" : [UIImage imageNamed:@"person2.jpeg"]};
    NSDictionary *user3 = @{@"username" : @"iTechie", @"email" : @"theRealApple@me.com", @"password" : @"infiniteloop", @"age" : @30, @"profilePicture" : [UIImage imageNamed:@"person3.jpeg"]};
    NSDictionary *user4 = @{@"username" : @"Royal", @"email" : @"king@me.com", @"password" : @"IGotAPalace", @"age" : @0, @"profilePicture" : [UIImage imageNamed:@"person4.jpeg"]};

    NSArray *userArray = @[user1, user2, user3, user4];
    return userArray;
}

@end
```

and this is my viewdidload

```
self.users = [DMZUserData users];
NSLog(@"%@", self.users);
```

Comment: One (or more) of your images doesn't exist resulting in `nil`.

Comment: I think the error message tells you what's wrong. *Anything* in that list of dictionary values that could potentially be `nil` **is** `nil`.  Do some debugging and find it yourself.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: @maddy i had an image file on my left side in xcode..

Comment: @trojanfoe sorry bro but unfortunately i am currently studying in objective c for now so i am very noob.. i am just ask for your help on how to fix this error i spent more than a half day about this error :(

Comment: No problem.  Objective-C collection classes (including `NSDictionary`) cannot contain `nil` values.  Basically one of your image files is not being packaged into your app bundle.  To debug create a separate `NSImage` of each and run the code in a debugger to ensure they aren't `nil`.

Comment: @trojanfoe very helpful..it a bit confusing when I drag my image file  because i drag it several and similar name and the error is the file image.its not jpeg and the right its jpg..thank you for your quickly response..thank very much.. -SOLVED :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The error means you are trying to put `nil` in the dictionary (which is not allowed). Since you are building the dictionaries with string literals those can't be `nil`. This means the problem is with one or more of your images.

Try this to help find the problem:

```
+(NSArray *)users
{
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"person1.jpeg"];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"person2.jpeg"];
    UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"person3.jpeg"];
    UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"person4.jpeg"];

    NSDictionary *user1 = @{@"username" : @"master photographer", @"email" : @"worldtravel@me.com", @"password" : @"drowssap", @"age" : @24, @"profilePicture" : image1 };
    NSDictionary *user2 = @{@"username" : @"Lots of tots", @"email" : @"otterskips@me.com", @"password" : @"icecreamrocks", @"age" : @65, @"profilePicture" : image2 };
    NSDictionary *user3 = @{@"username" : @"iTechie", @"email" : @"theRealApple@me.com", @"password" : @"infiniteloop", @"age" : @30, @"profilePicture" : image3 };
    NSDictionary *user4 = @{@"username" : @"Royal", @"email" : @"king@me.com", @"password" : @"IGotAPalace", @"age" : @0, @"profilePicture" : image4 };

    NSArray *userArray = @[user1, user2, user3, user4];
    return userArray;
}
```

Now you can either use the debugger and see if `image1`, `image2`, `image3`, or `image4` is `nil` or add `NSLog` statements for each.

Keep in mind that filenames are case sensitive so be sure the name you pass to `imageNamed:` exactly matches the real filename. Also verify the images have the extension `jpeg` and not `jpg`. Make sure the images are being packaged in your resource bundle.

Comment: Also worth noting that, if an Xcode asset catalog is used, the extension should be omitted. Since the images are jpeg, this is likely not the case, but should still be mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

One of the UIImages you're trying to create are nil. 
Please add the following code as the first line of the method +(NSArray *)users

```
NSAssert([UIImage imageNamed:@"person1.jpeg"] != nil, @"Person 1 image does not exist");
NSAssert([UIImage imageNamed:@"person2.jpeg"] != nil, @"Person 2 image does not exist");
NSAssert([UIImage imageNamed:@"person3.jpeg"] != nil, @"Person 3 image does not exist");
NSAssert([UIImage imageNamed:@"person4.jpeg"] != nil, @"Person 4 image does not exist");
```

That snippet of code will print on console what of the images does not exist. 
Run please on DEBUG and let's see what the result of the assertions is.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The better cure probably is to make the "NSDictionary" like this:

```
NSDictionary *user1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: my obj & key here, nil];
```

Comment: How is this a better cure?

Comment: Simply because this method: 

+ (id) dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)firstObject, ...

return an exception for nil key...
istead of:

- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary copyItems:(BOOL)flag

(I think this method is called for the example here)...that appear to return nothing about nil keys

Answer (score 2):

"***attempt to insert nil object from objects[4]***" means that either the key or value at index [4] is nil.

So as the others have said it would be one of your images since the key at index [4] is a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

It means that one of the values you're trying to put in that dictionary is nil, most likely one of the pictures. You might try assigning the images to variables and inspecting them to see if this is the case.